# PHP strtotime returns whole year instead of a single day

Tags: php, strtotime

I am currently using PHP `ROUND` , `ABS` , `STRTOTIME` to calculate the difference between two dates.

The calculation works until you select a `$_SESSION['b_checkout']` from a new year. i.e. if the `b_checkin` is Dec 30 and the `b_checkout` is Dec 31, this returns the correct `$no_nights` as 1 day.

`$_SESSION['b_checkin']` and `$_SESSION['b_checkout']` are using `'D F jS Y'` date format. e.g.

```
$_SESSION['b_checkin'] = "Wednesday, 31 December, 2014"
$_SESSION['b_checkout'] = "Thursday, 1 January, 2015"

$no_nights = round(abs(strtotime($_SESSION['b_checkout']) - strtotime($_SESSION['b_checkin']))/(60*60*24));
```

Currently this outputs (`echo $no_nights`) 363 days instead of 1 day. What is the problem?

Comment: Your dates are not valid formats for `strtotime` -> `int strtotime ( string $time) time A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the commas and see it works!

```
$b_checkin = "Wednesday 31 December 2014";
$b_checkout = "Thursday 1 January 2015";

$no_nights = round(abs(strtotime($b_checkout) - strtotime($b_checkin))/(60*60*24));
echo $no_nights;
```

When php can't interpret the year correctly, it uses the current year for parsing. thats how you are getting 363 days as result.

Comment: Used str_replace as follows and that worked: $_SESSION['b_checkin'] = str_replace(',', '', $_SESSION['b_checkin']);
$_SESSION['b_checkout'] = str_replace(',', '', $_SESSION['b_checkout']);

Answer (score 0):

Use below format for checkin and checkout

```
// 'F jS Y'
$_SESSION['b_checkin'] = "31 December, 2014";
$_SESSION['b_checkout'] = "1 January, 2015";
```

Hope this helps ;)

Cheers!!!